# Width and distance when using line patterns in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style

I am trying to make a cross hatch polygon fill (example link attached) using the values (defined by law) of 0.1mm for line width and 0.8mm for distance between the lines. But I don't get/see any hatch with such a small values, so I'd like to know if the values less than 1mm are supported anyway or I have to solve this differently?

[image]

Comment: Well, the example you are linking is more like 1,2 mm distance and probably 0,25 mm line width. If you use those values the resulting pattern will look much closer to your example.

Comment: EDIT: I just tried to print a 0,1mm/0,8mm crosshatch pattern from my CAD - it's barely readable. there is a reason the smallest line width is usually 0,18 mm ;).

Answer (score 2):

First go into your layer properties and then style. Hit the plus button below Symbol Layers; it should load up a simple fill symbol. In the symbol layer type section on the right select "Line Pattern Fill" and then you can set the angle, line width etc. Repeat this so you have two "Line Pattern Fill" symbol layers and just set them up with the same attributes EXCEPT have the angles set perpendicular to one another.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think his problem is that the resulting crosshatch pattern is not recognizable in QGIS - I just tried his values, it's the same for me... (see above)

Comment: yep...with those values it doesn't work :-(